# "uwsgi entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly" in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant

I used Vagrant to deploy a VM that creates 2 docker containers using docker-compose. They both run, but *web_sc* (webserver container, **tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask**) has this in it's log:
`uwsgi entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly`.
The complete log: https://codeshare.io/G81z7Z
Because of this, the webserver only returns **Error 502: Bad Gateway**. All I'm doing is booting it up with `vagrant up --provision`. Anyone that knows how to fix it? Thanks.

**Docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web_sc:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: web_sc
        network_mode: bridge
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        links:
          - "db_sc:db_sc"
        volumes:
          - /vagrant/www/application:/root
          - /vagrant/www/application/app:/app
        depends_on:
          - "db_sc"
    
    db_sc:
      image: mariadb
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: db_sc
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
         - /vagrant/www/application/app/sql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      restart: always 
      environment:
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: names
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passwd
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7
RUN apk --update add bash nano
ENV STATIC_URL /static
ENV STATIC_PATH /var/www/app/static
COPY ./requirements.txt /var/www/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /var/www/requirements.txt
#verbinding & data retrieve uit DB
#RUN apk add mariadb-connector-c
RUN apk add python3
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
RUN pip install mysql-connector-python
```

**Vagrantfile** (if necessary):

```
$script = <<-SCRIPT
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install sl -y
mkdir -p /vagrant/www/application/app
mkdir -p /vagrant/www/application/app/sql/init
mkdir -p /vagrant/www/application/app/sql/data
apt-get install links -y
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306

  config.vm.provision :docker
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose, yml: "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml", run: "always"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
  config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/yanni/OneDrive - Thomas More/Thomas More/2CCS1/Eerste Semester/Linux Webservices/Shipping Challenge/VagrantShit", "/vagrant"
end
```

**uwsgi.ini**:

```
[uwsgi]
module = main
callable = app
master = true
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using docker, try to clear the cache using

> `sail composer clearcache`

and after it

> `sail composer install`